# PHP variable authentication

Tags: php, security

Is it a bad idea to write a file with php for authentication?

An example:

A user submits a login form. If the credentials are invalid, the PHP writes a new file with the filename as the attempted username, and the contents would have a variable containing the number of attempts. Then that file would be included for the next login attempt, and if login attempts= 2 or whatever, display a reCaptcha.

Are there any obvious flaws with such a technique? I see most suggest using a database to store the login attempts and such, and I have no problem with doing it that way, but I was just curious.

Comment: Is it not possible to use a database? Aah didn't read the last line ;)

Comment: You can't really savely track login attemps - so best way would be to ask for a captcha code once on very first call. If successful, save somthing = TRUE to you session and continue, else show captcha 1 or 2 times again - after that show just nothing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file is just another form of a database. If you implement this solution carefully, there is no real difference between implementing this via a database or via files.

The problem is the extra overhead of managing the sessions via files and writing all the code to do this properly.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of it that way.

Answer (score 0):

In the end a database operates on files as well except for databases in memory.
Handling files yourself is not very efficient. Databases solve some complicated problems that you will face when writing/reading to files yourself like mentioned here [database vs. flat files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356851/database-vs-flat-files)

Comment: But that isn't that still vulnerable to brute force attacks?

Comment: How do you mean? You have a question about storing a login attempt counter.

Comment: The logic behind that being that writing to a file is safer than storing a session or using a database. Sorry for not elaborating