# Java: Input File Renamer

Tags: java

I am currently writing an input file renamer, to ensure that all my input values have an unique name. However I am now wondering how to store the unique name, most likely being an integer + extension.

I have considered this so far:

- **Database.** Might be slow, always needs a connection up.
- **Registry.** Not sure if you would want to use registry for a simple counter like this, which will be modified a lot.
- **Plain text file.** Seems like most simple option, but is prone to easy deletion, hence does not offer that much 'security' as database/registry.

The renamer will act like this:

- Input `randomstrings.pdf` -> `1.pdf`
- Input `notrandomatall.pdf` -> `2.pdf`
- Input `abcdef.pdf` -> `3.pdf`
- etc.

It needs to be persistent over multiple executions of the program and system (server) shutdown/failure aswell.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356851/database-vs-flat-files) given:

> 1. Databases can handle querying tasks, so you don't have to walk over
>      file manually. Databases can handle very complicated queries.
> 2. Databases can handle indexing tasks, so if tasks like get record
>      with id = x can be VERY fast
> 3. Databases can handle multiprocess/multithread access.
> 4. Databases can handle access from network
> 5. Databases can watch for data integrity
> 6. Databases can update data easily (see 1) )
> 7. Databases are reliable
> 8. Databases can handle transactions and concurrent access
> 9. Databases + ORMs let you manipulate data in very programmer
>      friendly.

Answer (score 1):

The classic suggestion is just to generate a random sequence of characters (6 alphanumeric usually suffices), and just try a different filename if the target filename already exists. After all, the filesystem does already store information about the used filenames, so there's really no need to store that information *again* in some other form (database, registry, etc.).

Comment: The files move to different folders and subfolders though, so I do not always know where they are. However there is a to-be-checked list in my database, which absolutely may not have duplicate filenames. So I cannot simply check if a file already exists.

Comment: So you already have a database? Why not use that if you need to hit the database anyway?

Comment: It is definately a possibility. But I was asking about the best-practice in the OP. A downside though is that no input files can be processed anymore if the database/connection is down.

Comment: Couldn't you pull a list of to-be-checked into a set or a map from the database (or wherever)? Then serialize it however you want, and let the contract for map and set take care of all that uniqueness business? Or am I misunderstanding your needs?