# Find the time since index.php was last visited, widget

Tags: php, html, widget

I've done a fair amount of searching on the internet to find a solution to this issue; however, I am still unable to find a real answer.

I would like to have a widget on my site that shows the user how long in seconds it has been since someone last visited the website. For example the clock would reset to '0' if someone were the refresh the page.

Not to be be confused with the time since a specific individual last visited the site, I'm asking to find the time since ANYONE sent a request for `index.php` .

I assume the way to do this is tied up in a large amount of PHP, of which I am not great at. Any help, advice or pointers anyone could give would be great! Many thanks in advance.

Lastly to prevent more confusion the clock does not need to be live on the browser. It would just change each time the page is reloaded.

Comment: I'd have a 2 column table, page (varchar), lastvisit (datetime) and update the lastvisit column on each load. You'd have to manually create the page records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to (as you said in your question) **find the time since ANYONE sent a request for index.php** is as follows:

Make a little `viewer.txt` file where you store the last timestamp information, and overwrite it with the function `time()` of the latest user visit in unix seconds, as follows. Then compare with the current time, on another file. (This method is much easier than sockets, and resembles a little database). I've programmed this code for you, put it on the page that you wish. It's completely functional, and I have tested it:

**File 1 (tracking and storing latest user visit):**

```
<?php

$file = fopen("viewer.txt", "w");

fwrite($file, "".time()."");

fclose($file);

?>
```

**File 2 (comparing current time with last user visit):**

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents("viewer.txt");

$file = (int)$file;

echo "Difference in time from last visit in seconds:";

echo $file - time();

?>
```

Mark this answer with the checkmark on the side of it if it helped.

Feel free to ask for more of my help if you have more questions.

Comment: I preferred text files over databases a while ago but DBs have quite a few advantages over text files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356851/database-vs-flat-files I don't think the bast way to handle any data is with text files. For example think about 10 or 100 users visiting the OP's page at once with this solution.

Comment: For something that isn't gigantic scale and will only store a few bytes of data, I don't see what the issue is. Though I agree with your point overall. @chris85

Comment: Many thanks, the project is currently on a very small scale, however I shall investigate into using databases for a solution aswell. Many thanks!

Comment: Could you mark my answer with a checkmark? @ThankYOU I did put effort into it.

Comment: Hi sorry, yes I shall. Just a quick question, this is at the top of my index.php.

`<?php
$file = fopen("viewer.txt", "w");
fwrite($file, "".time()."");
fclose($file);
?>

<?php
$file = file_get_contents("viewer.txt");
$file = (int)$file;
$realtime = $file - time();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
.
.
. 
etc`

Then later on I have put `<?php echo $realtime; ?>`

I have also got a viewer.txt in the same directory, however the reading is only showing 0, even after being left for a few minutes.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure, no problem. And no, you should put the first script at the end of the page, and the last one first. :) @ThankYOU It's the other way around, so that the file gets written AFTER the previous file has been outputted.