# Static Or Dynamic?

Tags: database, performance, caching, dynamic, static

I am going to be hosting 100's of thousands of pages, only a few KB, each with the exact same format. I originally thought of using a central database, but then thought that as the content on each page will never change, is it worth the unnecessary database requests? I originally thought of using something like memcache, but then, as stated above, thought it wouldn't be too efficient as the content will never change.

Question:
As the content is only a few KB per page, is it actually that inefficient to serve as static pages?
Could it affect the ability to search through the content to find the page, and how? Eg:
There will be a description on the page, when the user is using the search function it will need to search through the descriptions of each page.
One thing on the individual pages will change, but only once every few weeks/months, should I use a database for that, or serve that statically?

Comment: We don't do "please list advantages & disadvantages of x" type questions I'm afraid (any more). There's loads of existing information though:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356851/database-vs-flat-files

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/when-should-use-of-database-be-preferred-over-parsing-data-from-a-text-file

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/190482/why-use-a-database-instead-of-just-saving-your-data-to-disk

Comment: And anything else on pages 1-5 of Googling `should i use database or files`