# Working with Time Series: databases vs flat files

Tags: r, database, statistics, time-series

I have a collection of large time series files (with tick data) in `.txt.` format. I access these through `R` for statistical analysis. I am exploring moving the files to a Database (e.g. `MySQL`, `Influx`). The SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2356911/6143363) lays out the benefits of using a Database instead of flat files. I fail to see much value in the points raised there, maybe due to ignorance.

**For those working with time series, what kind of requirements would justify the additional complexity of setting up a Database**, instead of simply importing the flat files directly into `R`/`Python`/`Matlab`?

**Specific circumstances:**  Each file consists of no more than 10 columns (exact # depends on asset class) and in many cases millions of rows (sometimes less because I split them into smaller chunks). A few files get updated/rewritten in real time. I load the `.txt` files into `R` (either one at a time, or multiple files) at the beginning of a script, then create a number of binary vectors/signals, and perform statistical analyses/modelling. I do this on a computer with 128gb RAM, yet sometimes I run out of memory.

Thank you.